# Create new data set with updated value in selected column in Toad

Tags: sql, toad

I just started working with Toad for about half a year or so, and I just got myself quite a puzzle.

So here is the data set I'm working with

Table 1

| ID | Name | Amount | KEY | OTHER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CT | Total | 10,000 | 69 | INFO |

Table 2

| ID | Name | Amount | KEY | OTHER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C1 | A | 100 | 1 | INFO |
| C2 | B | 2000 | 2 | INFO |
| C3 | C | 150 | 3 | INFO |
| C10 | H | 50 | 10 | INFO |

DATA

| ID | Name | Amount | KEY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C1 | A | 100 | 1 |
| C2 | B | 2000 | 2 |
| C3 | C | 150 | 3 |
| C10 | H | 50 | 10 |

So the Amount in Table 1 = Total Amount in Table 2 = 10,000.
I have to transform table 1 into table 2 via the DATA table with KEY as a connection.
So basically you break Total of 10,000 from CT into C1 to C10. I'm stuck as whether to create 10 line of same code for C1 to C10. Is there a loop to update this? Since my table has like 70 columns and I only need to update the amount in 10 columns.

Cheers for the help guys!

Comment: I don't understand the question. KEY is a connection? How? It is 69 in Table 1, and has various values in Table 2.  Why would you break 10.000 from CT into 10 rows (and not only 1 or 39 or 100)? DATA looks exactly like Table 2, so - what is its purpose? What *rule* leads to amounts in Table 2 / DATA tables?

Comment: Oh, yes - which database do you use? Code depends on that.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.
So the problem is I have 10 orders which were input as 1 sale for 10,000. For the sake of proper record, I have to break them out into 10 small order with different values. These were tracked on an excel file (DATA), which is now I have to break them out based on DATA table. and I have to map the KEY as new ID (C+'KEY') for those to replace the data in Table 1. 
Anyway, I just went and fix the Procedures which goes line by line. Just wonder if there is any looping as a more compact solution.